# Validation of RAML file

Tags: validation, swagger, raml, wadl

suppose that we have some Swagger 2.0 document, e.g.
http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

I am trying to convert it to another formats using Apimatic.
https://apimatic.io/transformer

If I convert the Petstore Swagger document to WADL, the result seems to be invalid.
I have validated the WADL file against
https://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/wadl.xsd

Generally, I need to convert Swagger either to WADL or to RAML.
I am trying conversion from Swagger to RAML with Apimatic as an alternative because the convertion to WADL did not work.

Is there a way (online or offline tool) to check that the resulting RAML file is valid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Online: the "Design Center" at https://anypoint.mulesoft.com

Offline: go to https://raml.org/projects and click on the Design tab

Also in the latter check the "Utilities" tab, there are swagger to RAML converters there.

Comment: This seems to be an overkill for such simple task as validating a RAML file. The input is a RAML file (possibly invalid). The output should be a boolean value: valid / invalid. If invalid, a string message with validation error would be nice. Provide clear instructions how to achieve this with API Manager please.

Comment: Don't know of an online tool that does that. Ther parsers on the raml.org projects page do exactly that, they will parse your RAML and give validation errors, how to use depends on which you choose. For the API Manager: 1) you register, 2) you add a new API, 3) open the designer, 4) paste your RAML, 5) see if it has validation errors....(if it loads the graphical view on the right it doesn't)

Comment: To be honest, I am still lost. I have registered, added a new API ...and do not know where the designer is. I have uploaded a screenshot. http://www.uschovna.cz/en/zasilka/QR5GI7HR43ANB9R8-74X/

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I see an "API designer" section in that screen, not sure why is different from yours. I checked registering again and now you have to go to the "Design Center" (from the upper left corner menu) and Create an API Specification.